# What is the most efficient way to update images in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

This topic has been on my mind the last little while and I have been thinking about the efficiency for DOM updates relating to replacing / updating images. I haven't been able to find a discussion on this specifically and I am not even sure if there is an ideal solution between the two options I'll show below.

The best answer I've come up with is that is it totally dependent on if you need to update additional attributes on the `<img>` tag like the `alt`, `width`, `height` values if they are being used.

Ok, so say you want to update an image or do an image swap between two images, what do you believe is the most efficient or elegant way. Is it better to replace the `<img>` element completely with a new `<img>` element with an updated `src` or to only update the existing `<img>`'s `src` value with the new image?

The example I have use small images, would performance be effected by image size or whatever.

The two ways I have are:

```
$('.swapimage_ele').on("click", function(evt){
    var img1 = $("#img1").html();
    var img2 = $("#img2").html();

    $("#img1").html(img2);
    $("#img2").html(img1);
});

$('.swapimage_src').on("click", function(evt){
    var img1 = $("#img1 img").attr("src");
    var img2 = $("#img2 img").attr("src");

    $("#img1 img").attr("src", img2);
    $("#img2 img").attr("src", img1);
});
```

​
The quick working example I've wrote showing the two options is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jshaw/KMmeR/

Just curious on everyone's opinion or preference and if there's an ideal way of doing this.

Comment: What has your testing revealed so far?

Comment: I've put together a couple tests from the solutions provided in the replies and switching the image src with vanilla JS is the most efficient solution. After seeing these tests run thought it certainly makes since why @IHateLazy's solution works the best. Thanks! [Here are my tests.](http://jsperf.com/image-swap-efficiency)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Less jQuery, and definitely not using `.html()`

```
$('.swapimage_src').on("click", function(evt){
    var img1 = document.querySelector("#img1 img");
    var img2 = document.querySelector("#img2 img");

    var temp = img1.src;
    img1.src = img2.src;
    img2.src = temp;
});
```

Or if you must support IE6/7:

```
$('.swapimage_src').on("click", function(evt){
    var img1 = document.getElementById("img1").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    var img2 = document.getElementById("img2").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

    var temp = img1.src;
    img1.src = img2.src;
    img2.src = temp;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it better to replace the  element completely with a new  element with an updated src or to only update the existing 's src value with the new image?

Element creation will be more costly than changing an attribute. Especially if done via `innerHTML` as in your code. However, you should not need to change anything, you can just grab the elements from the DOM and change their positions:

```
$('#swapimage_dom').on("click", function(e){
    var img1 = $("#img1"),
        img2 = $("#img2");
    var imgEl = img1.find("img");
    img2.find("img").appendTo(img1);
    imgEl.appendTo(img2);
});
```

> The example I have use small images, would performance be effected by image size or whatever.

The DOM manipulation is cheap. You will not notice any difference between the methods, it's negligible. The reflow process, which might be a bit different, should be fast enough not to be noticable.

However, repainting - which is the same as the DOM manipulations have the same result - is a task that needs memory and some time. And this will increase with image size, of course. Yet you can't get around that.

Answer (score 0):

Did some experimentation with this for a mobile project involving extremely high resolution images and swapping them.

Swapping the src is faster than creating a new element.

However, another alternative is layering two images on top of each other and changing the z-indexes to swap which one is visible.  (or having one image off screen and swapping their positions)  This doesn't work if you want to be able to swap it with any dynamic image, or if you have more than just a few images to swap between.